# Bad ID3 tags when transferring mp3 to another device

Tags: command-line, audio, mp3, id3

I created mp3 files in Linux with the `mp3wrap` application and then I applied ID3 tags on it as follows:

```
$ for i in *.mp3; do mp3info -t ${i%.*} -l yes1 -a yes $i; done
```

When I look at a particular mp3 file (e.g. ddi.mp3) it looks as follows:

```
$ mp3info ddi.mp3 
File: ddi.mp3
Title:   ddi                            Track: 
Artist:  yes
Album:   yes1                           Year:  
Comment:                                Genre:  [255]
```

I copied the mp3 files on my Android device. There is no audio player app showing correctly and sorting according to my ID3 tags.
It shows instead title `File wrapped with Mp3Wrap` and artist/album
`http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net`

Is it possible to correct this ID3 information and enforce the correct ID3 tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `mp3info` write only ID3v1 tags. You can check it with something like `eyeD3` (a tool written in python):  `eyeD3 -1 file.mp3` (to check ID3v1) and `eyeD3 -2 file.mp3` (to check IDv2, which is read by recent players).

You can also use `eyeD3` to write v1 or v2 tags.

For instance, you can edit v2 tags with:

```
eyeD3 -2 -a "The Artist" -A "Album Name" -t "Title of the song" /tmp/song.mp3
```